d3 zoomable circle packing does not display labels when zooming in in angular v.18
everyone I managed to create zoomable circle packing using d3 in angular, every thing works fine even the zoom, but when I zoom in the labels of the children circles does not appear, and When I zoom out the labels of the parent circles disappear too.

this what happens when I zoom in, no labels are shown

also this is what happen when I zoom out, all labels disapper

import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  OnChanges,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-zoomable-circle-packing-chart',
  templateUrl: `./zoomable-circle-packing-chart.component.html`,
  standalone: true,
  styleUrls: ['./zoomable-circle-packing-chart.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ZoomableCirclePackingChartComponent
  implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges
{
  @ViewChild('chart', { static: true }) chartContainer!: ElementRef;

  private margin = 20;
  private diameter = 960;
  private color: any;
  private pack: any;
  private svg: any;
  private g: any;
  private root: any;
  private focus: any;
  private view: any;
  private circle: any;
  private node: any;
  private data = {
    name: 'flare',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'analytics',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'cluster',
            children: [
              { name: 'AgglomerativeCluster', size: 3938 },
              { name: 'CommunityStructure', size: 3812 },
              { name: 'HierarchicalCluster', size: 6714 },
              { name: 'MergeEdge', size: 743 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'graph',
            children: [
              { name: 'BetweennessCentrality', size: 3534 },
              { name: 'LinkDistance', size: 5731 },
              { name: 'MaxFlowMinCut', size: 7840 },
              { name: 'ShortestPaths', size: 5914 },
              { name: 'SpanningTree', size: 3416 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'optimization',
            children: [{ name: 'AspectRatioBanker', size: 7074 }],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'animate',
        children: [
          { name: 'Easing', size: 17010 },
          { name: 'FunctionSequence', size: 5842 },
          {
            name: 'interpolate',
            children: [
              { name: 'ArrayInterpolator', size: 1983 },
              { name: 'ColorInterpolator', size: 2047 },
              { name: 'DateInterpolator', size: 1375 },
              { name: 'Interpolator', size: 8746 },
              { name: 'MatrixInterpolator', size: 2202 },
              { name: 'NumberInterpolator', size: 1382 },
              { name: 'ObjectInterpolator', size: 1629 },
              { name: 'PointInterpolator', size: 1675 },
              { name: 'RectangleInterpolator', size: 2042 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'ISchedulable', size: 1041 },
          { name: 'Parallel', size: 5176 },
          { name: 'Pause', size: 449 },
          { name: 'Scheduler', size: 5593 },
          { name: 'Sequence', size: 5534 },
          { name: 'Transition', size: 9201 },
          { name: 'Transitioner', size: 19975 },
          { name: 'TransitionEvent', size: 1116 },
          { name: 'Tween', size: 6006 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'data',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'converters',
            children: [
              { name: 'Converters', size: 721 },
              { name: 'DelimitedTextConverter', size: 4294 },
              { name: 'GraphMLConverter', size: 9800 },
              { name: 'IDataConverter', size: 1314 },
              { name: 'JSONConverter', size: 2220 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'DataField', size: 1759 },
          { name: 'DataSchema', size: 2165 },
          { name: 'DataSet', size: 586 },
          { name: 'DataSource', size: 3331 },
          { name: 'DataTable', size: 772 },
          { name: 'DataUtil', size: 3322 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'display',
        children: [
          { name: 'DirtySprite', size: 8833 },
          { name: 'LineSprite', size: 1732 },
          { name: 'RectSprite', size: 3623 },
          { name: 'TextSprite', size: 10066 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'flex',
        children: [{ name: 'FlareVis', size: 4116 }],
      },
      {
        name: 'physics',
        children: [
          { name: 'DragForce', size: 1082 },
          { name: 'GravityForce', size: 1336 },
          { name: 'IForce', size: 319 },
          { name: 'NBodyForce', size: 10498 },
          { name: 'Particle', size: 2822 },
          { name: 'Simulation', size: 9983 },
          { name: 'Spring', size: 2213 },
          { name: 'SpringForce', size: 1681 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'query',
        children: [
          { name: 'AggregateExpression', size: 1616 },
          { name: 'And', size: 1027 },
          { name: 'Arithmetic', size: 3891 },
          { name: 'Average', size: 891 },
          { name: 'BinaryExpression', size: 2893 },
          { name: 'Comparison', size: 5103 },
          { name: 'CompositeExpression', size: 3677 },
          { name: 'Count', size: 781 },
          { name: 'DateUtil', size: 4141 },
          { name: 'Distinct', size: 933 },
          { name: 'Expression', size: 5130 },
          { name: 'ExpressionIterator', size: 3617 },
          { name: 'Fn', size: 3240 },
          { name: 'If', size: 2732 },
          { name: 'IsA', size: 2039 },
          { name: 'Literal', size: 1214 },
          { name: 'Match', size: 3748 },
          { name: 'Maximum', size: 843 },
          {
            name: 'methods',
            children: [
              { name: 'add', size: 593 },
              { name: 'and', size: 330 },
              { name: 'average', size: 287 },
              { name: 'count', size: 277 },
              { name: 'distinct', size: 292 },
              { name: 'div', size: 595 },
              { name: 'eq', size: 594 },
              { name: 'fn', size: 460 },
              { name: 'gt', size: 603 },
              { name: 'gte', size: 625 },
              { name: 'iff', size: 748 },
              { name: 'isa', size: 461 },
              { name: 'lt', size: 597 },
              { name: 'lte', size: 619 },
              { name: 'max', size: 283 },
              { name: 'min', size: 283 },
              { name: 'mod', size: 591 },
              { name: 'mul', size: 603 },
              { name: 'neq', size: 599 },
              { name: 'not', size: 386 },
              { name: 'or', size: 323 },
              { name: 'orderby', size: 307 },
              { name: 'range', size: 772 },
              { name: 'select', size: 296 },
              { name: 'stddev', size: 363 },
              { name: 'sub', size: 600 },
              { name: 'sum', size: 280 },
              { name: 'update', size: 307 },
              { name: 'variance', size: 335 },
              { name: 'where', size: 299 },
              { name: 'xor', size: 354 },
              { name: '_', size: 264 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'Minimum', size: 843 },
          { name: 'Not', size: 1554 },
          { name: 'Or', size: 970 },
          { name: 'Query', size: 13896 },
          { name: 'Range', size: 1594 },
          { name: 'StringUtil', size: 4130 },
          { name: 'Sum', size: 791 },
          { name: 'Variable', size: 1124 },
          { name: 'Variance', size: 1876 },
          { name: 'Xor', size: 1101 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'scale',
        children: [
          { name: 'IScaleMap', size: 2105 },
          { name: 'LinearScale', size: 1316 },
          { name: 'LogScale', size: 3151 },
          { name: 'OrdinalScale', size: 3770 },
          { name: 'QuantileScale', size: 2435 },
          { name: 'QuantitativeScale', size: 4839 },
          { name: 'RootScale', size: 1756 },
          { name: 'Scale', size: 4268 },
          { name: 'ScaleType', size: 1821 },
          { name: 'TimeScale', size: 5833 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'util',
        children: [
          { name: 'Arrays', size: 8258 },
          { name: 'Colors', size: 10001 },
          { name: 'Dates', size: 8217 },
          { name: 'Displays', size: 12555 },
          { name: 'Filter', size: 2324 },
          { name: 'Geometry', size: 10993 },
          {
            name: 'heap',
            children: [
              { name: 'FibonacciHeap', size: 9354 },
              { name: 'HeapNode', size: 1233 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'IEvaluable', size: 335 },
          { name: 'IPredicate', size: 383 },
          { name: 'IValueProxy', size: 874 },
          {
            name: 'math',
            children: [
              { name: 'DenseMatrix', size: 3165 },
              { name: 'IMatrix', size: 2815 },
              { name: 'SparseMatrix', size: 3366 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'Maths', size: 17705 },
          { name: 'Orientation', size: 1486 },
          {
            name: 'palette',
            children: [
              { name: 'ColorPalette', size: 6367 },
              { name: 'Palette', size: 1229 },
              { name: 'ShapePalette', size: 2059 },
              { name: 'SizePalette', size: 2291 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'Property', size: 5559 },
          { name: 'Shapes', size: 19118 },
          { name: 'Sort', size: 6887 },
          { name: 'Stats', size: 6557 },
          { name: 'Strings', size: 22026 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'vis',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'axis',
            children: [
              { name: 'Axes', size: 1302 },
              { name: 'Axis', size: 24593 },
              { name: 'AxisGridLine', size: 652 },
              { name: 'AxisLabel', size: 636 },
              { name: 'CartesianAxes', size: 6703 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'controls',
            children: [
              { name: 'AnchorControl', size: 2138 },
              { name: 'ClickControl', size: 3824 },
              { name: 'Control', size: 1353 },
              { name: 'ControlList', size: 4665 },
              { name: 'DragControl', size: 2649 },
              { name: 'ExpandControl', size: 2832 },
              { name: 'HoverControl', size: 4896 },
              { name: 'IControl', size: 763 },
              { name: 'PanZoomControl', size: 5222 },
              { name: 'SelectionControl', size: 7862 },
              { name: 'TooltipControl', size: 8435 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'data',
            children: [
              { name: 'Data', size: 20544 },
              { name: 'DataList', size: 19788 },
              { name: 'DataSprite', size: 10349 },
              { name: 'EdgeSprite', size: 3301 },
              { name: 'NodeSprite', size: 19382 },
              {
                name: 'render',
                children: [
                  { name: 'ArrowType', size: 698 },
                  { name: 'EdgeRenderer', size: 5569 },
                  { name: 'IRenderer', size: 353 },
                  { name: 'ShapeRenderer', size: 2247 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'ScaleBinding', size: 11275 },
              { name: 'Tree', size: 7147 },
              { name: 'TreeBuilder', size: 9930 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'events',
            children: [
              { name: 'DataEvent', size: 2313 },
              { name: 'SelectionEvent', size: 1880 },
              { name: 'TooltipEvent', size: 1701 },
              { name: 'VisualizationEvent', size: 1117 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'legend',
            children: [
              { name: 'Legend', size: 20859 },
              { name: 'LegendItem', size: 4614 },
              { name: 'LegendRange', size: 10530 },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'operator',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'distortion',
                children: [
                  { name: 'BifocalDistortion', size: 4461 },
                  { name: 'Distortion', size: 6314 },
                  { name: 'FisheyeDistortion', size: 3444 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'encoder',
                children: [
                  { name: 'ColorEncoder', size: 3179 },
                  { name: 'Encoder', size: 4060 },
                  { name: 'PropertyEncoder', size: 4138 },
                  { name: 'ShapeEncoder', size: 1690 },
                  { name: 'SizeEncoder', size: 1830 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'filter',
                children: [
                  { name: 'FisheyeTreeFilter', size: 5219 },
                  { name: 'GraphDistanceFilter', size: 3165 },
                  { name: 'VisibilityFilter', size: 3509 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'IOperator', size: 1286 },
              {
                name: 'label',
                children: [
                  { name: 'Labeler', size: 9956 },
                  { name: 'RadialLabeler', size: 3899 },
                  { name: 'StackedAreaLabeler', size: 3202 },
                ],
              },
              {
                name: 'layout',
                children: [
                  { name: 'AxisLayout', size: 6725 },
                  { name: 'BundledEdgeRouter', size: 3727 },
                  { name: 'CircleLayout', size: 9317 },
                  { name: 'CirclePackingLayout', size: 12003 },
                  { name: 'DendrogramLayout', size: 4853 },
                  { name: 'ForceDirectedLayout', size: 8411 },
                  { name: 'IcicleTreeLayout', size: 4864 },
                  { name: 'IndentedTreeLayout', size: 3174 },
                  { name: 'Layout', size: 7881 },
                  { name: 'NodeLinkTreeLayout', size: 12870 },
                  { name: 'PieLayout', size: 2728 },
                  { name: 'RadialTreeLayout', size: 12348 },
                  { name: 'RandomLayout', size: 870 },
                  { name: 'StackedAreaLayout', size: 9121 },
                  { name: 'TreeMapLayout', size: 9191 },
                ],
              },
              { name: 'Operator', size: 2490 },
              { name: 'OperatorList', size: 5248 },
              { name: 'OperatorSequence', size: 4190 },
              { name: 'OperatorSwitch', size: 2581 },
              { name: 'SortOperator', size: 2023 },
            ],
          },
          { name: 'Visualization', size: 16540 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.createChart();
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.createChart();
  }

  private createChart(): void {
    const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;

    // Clear the previous chart before creating a new one
    d3.select(element).selectAll('*').remove();
    console.log(element);
    // Set up color scale
    this.color = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 5])
      // @ts-ignore
      .range(['hsl(152,80%,80%)', 'hsl(228,30%,40%)'])
      // @ts-ignore
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);
    // Create SVG
    this.svg = d3
      .select(element)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.diameter)
      .attr('height', this.diameter)
      .attr(
        'style',
        `max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin: 0 -14px;; cursor: pointer;`
      )
      .style('background', this.color(-1));

    // Create chart
    this.g = this.svg
      .append('g')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        `translate(${this.diameter / 2},${this.diameter / 2})`
      );

    // Set up the pack layout
    this.pack = d3
      .pack()
      .size([this.diameter - this.margin, this.diameter - this.margin])
      .padding(2);

    this.root = d3
      .hierarchy(this.data)
      .sum((d) => (d as any).size)
      // @ts-ignore
      .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

    this.focus = this.root;

    const nodes = this.pack(this.root).descendants();
    console.log(nodes);

    this.circle = this.g
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', (d: any) =>
        d.parent ? (d.children ? 'node' : 'node node--leaf') : 'node node--root'
      )
      .style('fill', (d: any) => (d.children ? this.color(d.depth) : 'white'))
      .on('mouseover', function () {
        //   @ts-ignore
        d3.select(this).attr('stroke', '#000');
      })
      .on('mouseout', function () {
        //   @ts-ignore
        d3.select(this).attr('stroke', null);
      })
      .on(
        'click',
        (event: any, d: any) =>
          this.focus !== d && (this.zoom(event, d), event.stopPropagation())
      );

    // Add text
    const text = this.g
      .selectAll('text')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .style('fill-opacity', (d: any) => (d.parent === this.root ? 1 : 0))
      .style('display', (d: any) =>
        d.parent === this.root ? 'inline' : 'none'
      )
      .text((d: any) => (d.data as any).name);

    this.node = this.g.selectAll('circle,text');

    this.svg.on('click', (event: any) => this.zoom(event, this.root));

    this.zoomTo([this.root.x, this.root.y, this.root.r * 2 + this.margin]);
  }
  zoom(event: any, d: any) {
    const focus0 = this.focus;
    this.focus = d;

    const transition = d3
      .select(this.chartContainer.nativeElement)
      .transition()
      .duration(event ? (event.altKey ? 7500 : 750) : 750)
      .tween('zoom', () => {
        const i = d3.interpolateZoom(this.view, [
          this.focus.x,
          this.focus.y,
          this.focus.r * 2 + this.margin,
        ]);
        return (t) => this.zoomTo(i(t));
      });

    transition
      .selectAll('text')
      .filter(
        // @ts-ignore
        function (d: any) {
          return (
          // @ts-ignore
          d.parent === this.focus ||
            // @ts-ignore
            d3.select(this).style('display') === 'inline'
      )}
      )
    //   @ts-ignore
      .style('fill-opacity', function (d: any) {
        // @ts-ignore
        d.parent === this.focus ? 1 : 0;
      })
      .on('start', function(d: any)  {
        // @ts-ignore
        if (d.parent === this.focus) d3.select(this).style('display', 'inline');
      })
      .on('end', function(d: any) {
        // @ts-ignore
        if (d.parent !== this.focus) d3.select(this).style('display', 'none');
      });
  }
  zoomTo(v: any) {
    const k = this.diameter / v[2];
    this.view = v;
    this.node.attr(
      'transform',
      (d: any) => `translate(${(d.x - v[0]) * k}, ${(d.y - v[1]) * k})`
    );
    this.circle.attr('r', (d: any) => d.r * k);
  }
}


Note: i think the issue is in the zoom function, specifically the (this.focus)
please help!
I tried to use focus0, but it did not work

I can not figure out what you are attempting to do in the code that follows transition.selectAll('text').filter( in your zoom function.  Are you trying to hide all the text labels except for the node you zoomed on?

exactly, that's what I aim to do but it doesn't work, also when the user zooms out, I want these hidden parent circles to become visible
I used this code written in JS as a reference:
https://codepen.io/akeyz/pen/VwaOXjN
